# How can I do something at 9 and 109 and 209 etc, something else at 99 and 199 and 299 etc, and a sequence of other actions at all others ending in 9?

Tags: if-statement, math, dart

I have 1 sound that plays each time the score hits a number ending in 09.

I also have 4 sounds that play in sequence each time the score hits a number ending in 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, and 89.

I then I have 1 sound that plays each time the score hits a number ending in 99.

My code works but I feel like there should be a way to do this more elegantly.

```
          if (score == 9 || score == 109 || score == 209 ...) {
            play('sound1.mp3');
          }
          if (score == 19 || score == 59 || score == 119 || score == 159 ...) {
            play('sound2.mp3');
          }
          if (score == 29 || score == 69 || score == 129 || score == 169 ...) {
           play('sound3.mp3');
          }
          if (score == 39 || score == 79 || score == 139 || score == 179 ...) {
            play('sound4.mp3');
          }
          if (score == 49 || score == 89 || score == 149 || score == 189 ...) {
            play('sound5.mp3');
          }
          if (score == 99 || score == 199 ...) {
            play('sound6.mp3');
          }
```

Ideas? Please help me think about this like a programmer. :D

Comment: Please include your programming language. Your looking for a [modulo operation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: Thanks @steviestickman. I edited my question to include that I'm programming in Dart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's common between 9, 109, 209, etc  is that when divided by 100 they leave a **remainder of 9**.

What's common between 99, 199, 299, etc  is that when divided by 100 they leave a **remainder of 99**.

In Dart the remainder is computed with the modulo operator `%`.

```dart
var remainder = score % 100;
if (remainder == 9) {  
  // 9, 109, 209, ...
} else if (remainder == 99) { 
  // 99, 199, 299, ...
} else if (score % 10 == 9) { 
  // other numbers ending in 9
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joni! That definitely solves the issue of getting the numbers 9, 109, 209, ... and the numbers 99, 199, 299, ... For the other numbers ending in 9, I need to play 4 sounds sequentially. So, sound2 at 19, sound3 at 29, sound4 at 39, sound5 at 49, but then back to sound2 at 59, etc. 

I could make an int variable that increases each play and then resets each time it gets to 4, but that also feels less elegant. Is there a way to do this with modulos?

Comment: What I would do is extract `score % 100` to a new variable and then check if it's equal to 19 or 59, or 29 or 69, and so on. There are numerical tricks to shorten this, but code with a little bit of repetition will be easier to understand and maintain in the long term